Selecting today's rows based on UTC time
I have a table with a field called recordTime of type timestamp without time zone. I want to select today's rows only (i.e. since midnight). The records are sourced globally and arrive as UTC, so I need to select rows based on midnight UTC.
There seems to be a myriad of ways of doing this including ...
WHERE date_trunc('day', recordTime) = current_date ;

WHERE date_trunc('day', recordTime) = date_trunc('day', current_date at time zone 'utc') 

WHERE date_trunc('day', recordTime) = date_trunc('day', current_timestamp at time zone 'utc') 

WHERE recordTime >= '17-May-2024 00:00:00'

Which of these is best practice - or maybe a different method entirely? (Bearing in mind that performance seems similar in all cases.)

Add an index on recordTime and use  WHERE recordTime >= '17-May-2024 00:00:00'

I'd go with the one which is the most precise. As for performance, unless you benchmark, you can't really tell!

@Adam The OP wants records for just one day.

Correct, short, and fast
WHERE recordtime >= date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') 
AND   recordtime <  date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') + interval '1 day';

The 2nd line is optional if there cannot be rows past "today" in the table. (Would waste only very little performance in that case.)
The definition of "today" depends on the current time zone. Use the AT TIME ZONE construct.
date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') gets the start of the current day at time zone UTC. See:

PostgreSQL field timestamp without timezone - how to check if it equals today
Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL

now() is Postgres short syntax for standard SQL current_timestamp. See:

Difference between now() and current_timestamp

Include the starting 00:00, but exclude the ending 00:00.
Don't use BETWEEN with timestamp types.
Make the expression sargable. I.e., compare the bare column to a (computed) constant, not the other way round. Better in any case, especially to use a B-tree index on recordtime, which you should have unless the table is trivially small.
Shorter
If you are sure the timezone setting of the current session is 'UTC'.
One way to make sure is to set it yourself in the same transaction:
BEGIN;
SET timezone = 'UTC';

...
WHERE recordtime >= current_date
AND   recordtime <  current_date + 1;

You can add integer to a date to add days. And date is coerced to the column type timestamp [without time zone] cleanly in the expression.
Smarter
If time zones can be involved in any way, it's typically better to work with timestamptz columns to begin with. Then, to get rows for "today in the time zone UTC", use the convenient variant of date_trunc() taking the time zone as 3rd parameter (since Postgres 12):
WHERE recordtime >= date_trunc('day', now(), 'UTC') 
AND   recordtime <  date_trunc('day', now(), 'UTC') + interval '1 day';

Aside
Avoid mixed-case identifier in Postgres if at all possible. Else, you introduce uncertainty whether it's really recordtime or "recordTime". See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?


Today starts at midnight 00:00 and ends "tomorrow" also at midnight. Just use today and tomorrow:
WHERE recordTime BETWEEN 'today'::timestamp AND 'tomorrow'::timestamp

It's fairly straight forward and easy to read and understand. You can even do some additional interval calculations on these values, if needed.

Isn't 'today' and 'tomorrow' affected by time zones?

This will also pick up 19-May-2024 00:00 even if it's 18-May-2024.

@Schwern: 'today' is of type text so no: it's not affected by time zones. Then you can cast it to timestamp with or without time zone. And in both cases will be interpreted as '0:00:00' of the given type. So, 'today'::timestamp without time zone' will be midnight utc.

@bitifet. What? That is not true. Short version, there is no guarantee that  'today'::timestamp without time zone' will be Midnight at UTC.  Longer version,  'today'::timestamp without time zone' will be Midnight at whatever TimeZone is set on the Postgres server when the query is run. Since that can be set per session that could be anything.

@Schewrn: Of course you are right!!!
I had a happy idea and I didn't think twice (it's too late).
Right approach would be something like 'today'::timestamp - ((extract (timezone_hour from 'today'::timestamptz) || ' hours'))::interval. But thant's not so simple anymore...

@bitifet Time zones are a nightmare. I double checked and the results are in my answer.

@Schwern: Sure they are!! But check it again: If I'm not wrong now, you already fell in the trap (see first code block in my answer...)

WHERE date_trunc('day', recordTime) = date_trunc('day', current_timestamp at time zone 'utc') 

I don't know if this is best practice, but it has the advantage of being explicit about its conversions. It also avoids the gotcha of accidentally matching midnight the next day.
You can shorten it to:
WHERE recordTime::date = (current_timestamp at time zone 'utc')::date;


WHERE recordTime >= '17-May-2024 00:00:00'

Incorrect. This will match every recordTime after May 17th, including May 18th, May 19th, etc.
You'd instead write...
WHERE '17-May-2024'::date <= recordTime and recordTime < '18-May-2024'::date

This will match 17-May-2024 00:00 and will not match 18-May-2024 00:00.
You have to input the date manually, but that's a simple matter if you're running the query from a program.
Watch out using between. For example, where recordTime between '17-May-2024'::date and '18-May-2024'::date. This will match both dates. where recordTime between '17-May-2024'::date and '17-May-2024'::date is correct, but odd. It's better to write it out long-hand.

current_date is the date according to the current time zone, but it has no time zone information, so that's no good here. Also don't use synonyms like today and tomorrow.
test=# set timezone='Asia/Tokyo';
SET

test=# select current_date, 'today'::timestamp, 'tomorrow'::timestamp;
 current_date |      timestamp      |      timestamp      
--------------+---------------------+---------------------
 2024-05-18   | 2024-05-18 00:00:00 | 2024-05-19 00:00:00
(1 row)

test=# set timezone='America/Los_Angeles';
SET

test=# select current_date, 'today'::timestamp, 'tomorrow'::timestamp;
 current_date |      timestamp      |      timestamp      
--------------+---------------------+---------------------
 2024-05-17   | 2024-05-17 00:00:00 | 2024-05-18 00:00:00
(1 row)


Finally, the best thing for performance is to ensure recordTime is indexed.
